# Second Integral of Modified Bessel function $ k_o(z)$

Tags: improper-integrals, approximation, bessel-functions

I have been trying to code an algorithm but I have faced the following problem about the second integral of modified Bessel function $ k_o(z)$ can you please help ;

In the paper there is an approximation for second integral of $ k_o(z)$ defined as ;

$\lim_{x\to0} k_2(x)  = 1-\frac{pi}{2}*x+(\frac{3}{2}-ln\{\frac{e ^ {\gamma}}{2}-ln(x))*\frac{x^2}{2}$

I do not know how this approximation was derived and also since the above formula is only the limit for $ k_2(z)$ I want to know what is the complete form of the approximation of second internal of modified bessel function to use it in my code . Or do you think it is correct to use the equation above?

Please note that in the paper the first integral of modified bessel function $ k_o(z)$ is defined as

$ k_1(z)=\int_{x}^{\infty} k_0(z) dz$

and  $ k_2(z)$ is defined as second integrtal of  $ k_o(z)$  from x to $\infty$.

can some one please help as I have spent too much time on that with no result.

Thanks ,
Ehsan

Comment: Ugh, what a horrendous picture...

Comment: Actually , My basic problem is about second integral of bessel k that I do not know what does that mean and how to code it as it seems that both of them are from x to infinity